# Instalação angular 2

Tags: angular

Eu tenho um site pronto, ele é estático. Gostaria de instalar o Angular 2 nele.
Instalei o angular a partir do comando `npm install @angular/cli` e tentei colocar os arquivos html, css, jquery nele porém não estou conseguindo.

Alguém pode me explicar como faz? Obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro precisa fazer a instalação global do pacote utilizando o comando

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

em seguida, crie um projeto angular com o comando

```
ng new "nome do app"
```

ai você pode colocar seus arquivos na pasta src - app, seguindo sempre o padrão do angular que você pode aprender melhor no start guide do próprio angular

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cli-quickstart.html

Answer (score 0):

Conforme a própria documentação explica você deve utilizar o comando

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Para ter acesso a ferramenta na linha de comando que cria e gerencia projetos em angular. O motivo de não funcionar é que com a flag `-g` indica que você está instalando o pacote do NPM em modo global, ou seja, você vai poder usá-lo executando `ng [options]` após executar a instalação. Sem a flag você está instalando a cli do angular na sua pasta atual e não o angular em si.

Siga o tutorial inicial de Angular 2 para aprender como utilizar o framework corretamente.

Fonte: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cli-quickstart.html

Answer (score 0):

Para configurar seu ambiente de desenvolvimento Angular siga os seguintes passos:

Configuração do Angular:

**Downloads:

```
--> Node: https://nodejs.org/en/download/ (Windows Installer)
--> Git: https://git-scm.com/downloads
--> Visual Studio Code: https://code.visualstudio.com/download
```

**Após instalar o NODE e o Git, configure as variáveis de ambiente:**

..........................................Configurando a variável de ambiente...................................

*Vá em "Exibir Configurações Avançadas do Sistema" na barra de pesquisa do Windows e clique em "Variáveis de Ambiente..."

*Crie o path abaixo no campo, "Variáveis do Sistema"...

```
--> Clique em Novo...;
--> Nome da variável: PATH (Tudo maiúsculo);
--> Valor da variável: C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\NOME_DO_USUÁRIO\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
```

..............................................Testando..........................................................

*Instalando o Angular:

```
---> Abra o cmd:
---> Vá para a raiz;
---> Execute: "npm install -g @angular/cli".
```

*Criar um novo projeto:

```
---> Execute: "ng new projetoAngular":
---> Escreva Y e clique em Enter;
---> vá na opção SCSS com as setas e clique em Enter.
```

*Ver se o projeto foi criado corretamente:

```
---> Abra o projeto(folder) c:\projetoAngular no Visual Studio Code.
```

*Para iniciar o servidor:

```
---> Abra o cmd;
---> Vá para a raiz;
---> Entre na pasta projetoAngular (Cd projetoAngular);
---> Execute: "ng serve".
```

*Testando no navegador com:

```
---> localhost:4200.
```